# Netbeans: how to auto transfer standalone Java app's JAR file to remote location

Tags: java, file-upload, netbeans, jar, ftp

Does anyone know how to get Netbeans to auto transfer JAR files of standalone Java app to remote location?

I've searched the web over but have found nothing for JAR files.

I've looked into FTP Site Deployer plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer, which is aimed at JSP and PHP.

Another site I came across - http://ilite.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/using-ftp-from-within-netbeans/ - is also aimed at web development.

The dream solution/plug-in would be when I click on "clean and build", it will auto trasnfer to remote location.  If not, happy to do some more clicks after build to get it transferred.  Would love to do everything in Netbeans.

As to the method of transfer, am open to anything, whether it's via FTP or shell script (i'm using osx and remote location is a Debian box), or something else as long as it's open standard.

Any suggestions folks?  Thanks in advance.  Cheers.

Comment: What remote location?  You can set up a Maven plugin to upload the artifacts to a distribution server but you haven't said what you mean by _"auto trasnfer to remote location"_

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the quick reply.  My remote location is just a directory on a linux (debian) box.  My Netbeans project is not "Mavenized", thus would be looking for a solution that does NOT entail Maven?

Comment: Take a look at [Ant FTP task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html). Update the build.xml file in project directory, adding a "-post-jar" target, which will be executed each time you do a build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This assumes you are using the "Netbeans Project" project type, which is Ant based*

Start by taking a look at the [Apache Ant FTP task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html)

In your projects directory there is a `build.xml` file (switch to the "Files" tab and expand your project directory).

In here you can customise the build process by implementing the predefined tasks, as outlined in the `build.xml` comments...

One of these is the `-post-jar` target...

> -post-jar:                 called after JAR building

Create a new target named `-post-jar` and use the FTP task to upload your content, for example...

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <ftp server="ftp.apache.org"
            userid="anonymous"
            password="me@myorg.com"
            remotedir="...">
        <fileset dir="dist"/>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

*Nb: I've not tested this myself and you may be required to include some additional dependencies, read the docs!*

Comment: Brilliant - works exactly as per your instruction!  This solution is perfect for me and now that you've taught me about Ant tasks, I can explore other options.  Thanks a million MadProgrammer, very much appreciated!

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might consider making it's own "target" and running it manually, but that depends on you ;)